# How does FPGA knows the configuraton file is present in Flash memory during bootup?

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga

Which areas in flash memory are scanned during bootup to make sure that there is configuration file present in the external flash memory?

Comment: This is something your FPGA datasheet should tell.

Comment: Depends on the FPGA.  What FPGA are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

In general the FPGA does not know or care if the FPGA has a file present before it tries to load the configuration data. There is a CRC in the file that is checked at the end of configuration that the FPGA uses to determine if a valid configuration has been loaded. There is a signal called CONFIG_DONE that indicates if the configuration was successful.

Comment: In general it does not actually start loading config data until it reads the correct header at the start of the config data.